# Is there any TRICK to evaluate fast an integral in its range?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Lets say we have the following integral:

$$\int_{\sqrt{2}}^{2} (x^4-6x^2+8)\;\mathrm{d}x = \left[\frac{x^5}{5}-2x^3+8x\right]_{x=\sqrt{2}}^{x=2}$$

Is there any way to like grouping the integral to avoid doing the long process $F(b)-F(a)$ ?
How can I do this process faster ?

Comment: I can't see any effective way to do that. There is some special motivation for which you are looking to this alternative way?

Comment: @user once I saw a professor he was like factoring out and he only have to do a subtraction

Comment: You can probably do it faster by just doing it than by taking the time to find a trick. On an exam you should get nearly full credit for getting the algebra right. This is not the kind of calculation that will occur often other than in a class.

Comment: How specific an example is this integral? Are you looking for really good ways to evaluate *this specific polynomial* on *this specific range* $[\sqrt2,2]$ or are you looking for tricks that can shorten the computation in general?

Comment: @MishaLavrov in general

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the comments have advised, you should probably not be looking for tricks if you are trying to do well on your calculus exams. But if you are looking for clarification as to what your professor was doing, or perhaps you're trying to practice for some math competition, then this is maybe what you're looking for. Observe that
\begin{align*}
\left[\frac{x^5}{5}-2x^3+8x\right]_{\sqrt2}^2
&= \left[\frac{x^5}{5}\right]_{\sqrt2}^2
- \left[2x^3\right]_{\sqrt2}^2
+ \left[8x\right]_{\sqrt2}^2\\
&= \frac{2^5-(\sqrt{2})^5}{5}
- 2\left(2^3-(\sqrt{2})^3\right)
+ 8(2-\sqrt{2})
\end{align*}
In other words, you can just look term-wise, and you can ignore any operations **which commute with addition/subtraction** (like signs, or multiplication/division by a constant). In this example, when I plugged in my bounds, I could just "replace" $x^5$ with $2^5-(\sqrt{2})^5$. But this is often not advised for calculus students to do, because far too often the mistake of rewriting this as
$$
\frac{(2-\sqrt{2})^5}{5}
- 2(2-\sqrt{2})^3
+ 8(2-\sqrt{2})
$$
is made, which is NOT correct, and often leads to much confusion.